# microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework could not be found (rc1-final)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity, asp.net5

I tried to install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework RC1 with Nuget targeting .NET 4.5.1 using visual studio 2015

I have this issue everytime , tried on two different computer

**How to reproduce** :

In Visual Studio 2015 Community ,

File -> New -> Project -> Console Application (.NET 4.5.1 )
Run "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Pre" in package manager console
Build solution 
Error appear in the error list .

I tried to install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework RC1 with Nuget targeting .NET 4.5.1 using visual studio 2015

I have this issue everytime , tried on two different computer

How to reproduce :

In Visual Studio 2015 Community ,

File -> New -> Project -> Console Application (.NET 4.5.1 )
Run "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Pre" in package manager console
Build solution 
Error appear in the error list .

[image]

Comment: If you got a *.csproj file in your solution folder, you got the wrong project type. You need a ASP.NET Console application (will create *.xproj project file). The package manager console isn't used anymore in .NET COre projects, you use project.json and dnu restore/dotnet restore commands

Comment: It should be called something like "ASP.NET 5 Console Application" or "Console Applicatoin (package)", dunno on top of my head, don't have Visual Studio 2015 Installed here

Comment: None of the statements above are true. For a simple reason , microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework  target both .NET Core , and .NET 4.5.1 . Which mean it can be used with xproj and .NET Core project using "package.json" . NuGet is still used in .NET Core , it's just using a json file instead . I recommend you dig a bit more about .NET Core and .NET 4 .

Comment: I had no issues installing the package from "Console Application (package)". Doing the same in the old "Console Application" didn't worked. Try it out

Comment: I want to use this package in a .NET 4.5.1 project , not a .NET Core project .

Comment: Changed the tags. Time to upgrade to RC2 http://dot.net

Answer (score 0):

If you create a normal .NET Framework Console application (ones with *.csproj Project files) and use NuGet it won't correctly find the required dependencies.

You need to create a "Console Application (package)" to target .NET Core packages. One of the reasons is that .NET Core applications can target multiple platforms where the old Console and Class Libraries (except PCL) can only target one platform.

When compiling a .NET Core project (Class Library (Package) or Console Application (Package)), it will create 1 nuget package for each of the targets whereas with the old project templates you required 1 project for each targeting platform.

You'll be sure you got the correct project type if there is a `*.xproj` project file in your project folder and a `package.json`.

Comment: microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework  target .NET 4.5.1 and above . I recomend you check the nuget packages on nuget .